# Dictionary<string, double>get key from value (error)

Tags: c#, dictionary, contains

I have a dictionary (Dictionary) and I want to get key value from (value) for instance:

suppose the dic contains:

```
"som": 12.2345
"roy": 2.677
"toy": 1.67445666777
```

I want to get the roy key from searching about 2.677

I tried:

```
var keys = from entry in dic
                           where entry.Value == 2.677
                           select entry.Key;
```

and also :

```
var myKey =dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Contains(2.677)).Key;
```

in each case I got the same error which is :
Error:  'double' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'double' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show us the code that defines `dic`, I have a suspicion something is wrong there.

Comment: Show us the code where are you instantiating the dictionary. The second one should work, just omitting the  `.Contains` part. However knowing that @vnbrs answer doesn't help you, and judging by the error, I am almost sure `dic` is not a `Dictionary<string, double>` but `IEnumerable<double>`.

Comment: I have a list & dictionary so, my error was I used the name of list instead of dictionary so it works now :)))))))

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `Contains`. Try this:

```
var myKey = dic.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == 2.677).Key;
```

Note that `FirstOrDefault` method will return the **exact first** key or `null` if it doesn't find anything that matches the expression. Many keys can have the same `Value` property.

Comment: dictionary<string, double>

Comment: @vnbrs I removed my comment a bit ago, I was mistaken. OP has something wrong with their Dictionary instantiation.  The error they are getting: " 'double' does not contain a definition for 'Value'" is indicative that `dic` is not a `Dictionary<string, double>`

Comment: Please include the dictionary definition and instantiation in the question. @dany

Comment: @vnbrs really thanks a lot, my error was because I used list instead of dictionary their names almost the same with simple difference

Comment: @dany maybe you should take this as a lesson to give your variables more meaningful names...

Comment: Clean Code, chapter 2, "Meaningful names". Give it a try.

Comment: @vnbrs I really appreciate all that you have done. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string key = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == 2.677)?.Key;
```

Note that `FirstOrDefault()` can return a null if nothing matches your condition, so use the null conditional operator (`?.`) to make sure a null reference exception is not thrown.  This just means that key will be null if it cannot find a value that matches.